# How to increase fps opencv multi camera setup

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an OpenCV program that grabs images from 2 cameras at the same time as fast as possible.  In order to get both cameras to take images as close as possible I'm using the grab() and retrieve() functions.  The frame rate I'm getting is pretty slow right now (around 6 fps).  I would like to increase this fps.  Does anyone have any idea on how I can increase the fps?

I was thinking maybe put each camera on a different thread or utilizing multithreading in some way but I am afraid that they won't capture image at the same time that way.

```
void takeImages(VideoCapture& cap, VideoCapture& cap1, int imagecount){


    if(!cap.isOpened()|| !cap1.isOpened()) {  // check if we succeeded
        cout << "Can not open cameras." << endl;
        return;
    }


    Mat frame, frame2;
    for(int x = 0;x < imagecount; x++)
    {
        // Capture image from both camera at the same time (important).
        if( !cap.grab() || !cap1.grab() )
        {

            cout << "Can not grab images." << endl;
            return;
        }


        if( cap.retrieve(frame,3) || cap1.retrieve(frame,3)){

            //process images here..

        } else {
            cout << "Can not retrieve images." << endl;
            return;
        }

        printf("x = %d\n", x);
    }

    waitKey(0);
}



int main(int, char**)
{

    // trying to set higher program priority to increase fps here
    cout << "Nice = " << nice(21) << endl;

    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    VideoCapture cap1(1);


    namedWindow("cam1",1);
    namedWindow("cam2",1);

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    //Get the time it takes to get 200 frames from BOTH cameras.
    takeImages(cap,cap1, 200);

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end= std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Time difference = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - begin).count() <<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to double your fps by moving each camera to its own thread. To synchronize the cameras you can use the `std::chrono::steady_clock` to make sure they capture at the same time.

Maybe something like this:

```
#include <thread>

using steady_clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;

void takeImages(VideoCapture& cap, int imagecount,
    steady_clock::time_point next_frame, unsigned fps)
{
    assert(fps > 0);
    assert(fps <= 1000);

    Mat frame;
    for(int x = 0; x  < imagecount; x++)
    {
        // Capture image from both camera at the same time (important).
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(next_frame);
        next_frame += std::chrono::milliseconds(1000 / fps);

        if(!cap.grab())
            throw std::runtime_error("Can not grab image.");

        if(!cap.retrieve(frame, 3))
            throw std::runtime_error("Can not retrieve image.");

        // process image here

    }

    waitKey(0);
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    try
    {
        // trying to set higher program priority to increase fps here
        // cout << "Nice = " << nice(21) << endl;

        VideoCapture cap0(0); // open the default camera
        VideoCapture cap1(1 + CAP_V4L2);

        if(!cap0.isOpened() || !cap1.isOpened())
        {  // check if we succeeded
            cout << "Can not open cameras." << endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

//      namedWindow("cam1", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
//      namedWindow("cam2", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        // pass the same time point to both threads to synchronize their
        // frame start times
        steady_clock::time_point next_frame = steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(50);

        std::thread t1{takeImages, std::ref(cap0), 200, next_frame, 10};
        std::thread t2{takeImages, std::ref(cap1), 200, next_frame, 10};

        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Time difference = "
            << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - begin).count()
            << std::endl;
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I have to clarify that my fps is slow as is with out any processing yet and just running the code I have posted.  Would this help in that case?

Comment: @bakalolo Because `cap.retrieve()` is supposed to be the slower part the previous method may have provided some benefit. However I have posted a new method that should be much more efficient as it doesn't start new threads each iteration.

Comment: Seems like the waitkey was blocking my code and when I removed it its working well..

Answer (score 0):

How much fps do you get with a single camera? Multi-threading should be the solution to explore in order to increase your fps.